# Is there a find and replace application with multiple rules?

Tags: software-rec, find-and-replace

I'm looking for a search and replace tool that takes a list of rules and either a file (or directory) and runs those rules on the files.  I have a bunch of different things that need to be changed in many files, and I'd like to be able to run all the rules in one shot.

I was hoping I could put the rules separate file, and use the same set of rules over and over again.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I was looking for **sed**.  Using that with the -f option should do most of what I want.

www.sedtutorial.com is a good place to get started with the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

This tool does much more than what you're looking of, but can easily handle multiple rules:

http://www.parse-o-matic.com/parseomaticfree.aspx

Comment: does something like this exist that is free or OSS?  It's not for personal use. :\

Answer (score 0):

Wheater you want to add some simple rules, save them for later or add regexp multiline replacements [BK ReplaceEm](http://www.ecobyte.com/replacetext/) is for you ;-). But seriously. If you just want to quickly run some simple, specific modifications then this will probably not be the best of tools. But if you want to save the rules and not wonder every time how to do some conversion then this will work. I also like it because you can (but don't have to) save a folder and a file mask for which you will run replacements. You can also move the set of folders between replacement groups and run replacements in certain order.

Answer (score 0):

Check TextCrawler. Is the only program that has also a **Batch Commands - Batch Editor** (here you can put as many rules as you want for search and replace)

https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html

also, for regex and also for simple find and replace, you can use notepad++ plugin (Python), with rules for multiple Search and Replace. You can find the code here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function

from Npp import *
import os
import sys

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class T22601(object):

    def __init__(self):
        top_level_dir = notepad.prompt('Paste path to top-level folder to process:', '', '')
        number_files = 0
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_level_dir):
            nested_levels = root.split('/')
            if len(nested_levels) > 0:
                del dirs[:]
            for filename in files:
                if filename[-5:] == '.html':
                    notepad.open(root + "\\" + filename)
                    console.write(root + "\\" + filename + "\r\n")
                    notepad.runMenuCommand("Encodage", "Convertir en UTF-8")
                    regex_find_repl_dict_list = [
                        { 'find' : '<title>(.*?)</title>', 'replace' : r'\3\2\1' },
                        { 'find' : '<head>\s+', 'replace' : r'\n baba ' },
                    ]
                    editor.beginUndoAction()
                    for d in regex_find_repl_dict_list: editor.rereplace(d['find'], d['replace'])
                    editor.endUndoAction()
                    notepad.save()
                    notepad.close()
                    number_files += 1
        result = notepad.prompt('Number of modified files: ', '', number_files)
        print("Number of modified files: ", number_files)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__': T22601()
```